# glide load image failed, below is the stacl

Tags: android-glide

User
Failed to load resource There were 4 root causes: java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000) java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000) java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000) java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000) call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail

skip memory is not effect

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.